# Há alguma forma de usar tags html em uma interpolação?

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho um componente que chama um dialogo de confirmação, eu passo para o dialogo o titulo e a descrição do dialog dessa forma:

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalConfirmacaoGeral, { data: {tituloDialog: "Titulo do dialog de confirmacao", descricaoDialog: "Tags html dentro da interpolação<br>, testeeeee"}, panelClass: 'dialogpanel' })
```

No dialogo recebo esses dados e mostro no template através de interpolação:

```
<h5 class="tituloDialog"><strong>{{data.tituloDialog}}</strong></h5>

<p>{{data.descricaoDialog}}</p>
```

Os `<br>` estão sendo mostrados como parte da frase em vez de realizar a quebra de linha. É possível usar template literal dessa forma? Como posso fazer pro `<br>` funcionar? Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver dessa forma:

```
<p [innerHTML]="data.descricaoDialog"></p>
```